# Tkinter entry arguments : takes 0 positional arguments but 7 were given

Tags: python, tkinter, pulp

I'm trying to create a program using PuLP library that when you hit the button it solves a linear problem and outputs values. So this is what I get when I tried to optimize my input values:

```
TypeError: problem() takes 0 positional arguments but 7 were given.
```

At this point I am not sure I understand what this TypeError is trying to tell me.

```
from tkinter import*
from pulp import*

def problem():
    prob=LpProblem("problem", LpMaximize)
    x1=LpVariable("x1", lowBound=0)
    x2=LpVariable("x2", lowBound=0)
    x3=LpVariable("x3", lowBound=0)
    prob+= a*x1 +b*x2 +c*x3,
    prob+= d*x1 +e*x2 + f*x3 <= g,
    prob.solve ()
    print("status:", LpStatus[prob.status])
    for v in prob.variables():
        print (v.name, "=", v.varValue)
        print("objective=%s$" % value(prob.objective))
root =Tk()
root.title("System")
root.geometry("1300x500+0+0")
a=Entry(Top, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bd=8)
a.grid(row=1, column=1)

b=Entry(Top,  font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bd=8)
b.grid(row=1, column=2)

c=Entry(Top,  font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bd=8)
c.grid(row=1, column=3)

d=Entry(Top,  font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bd=8)
d.grid(row=2, column=1)

e=Entry(Top,  font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bd=8)
e.grid(row=2, column=2)

f=Entry(Top,  font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bd=8)
f.grid(row=2, column=3)

g=Entry(Top, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bd=8)
g.grid(row=3, column=1)

def inserter (value):
    w.delete("0.0", "end")
    w.insert("0.0", value)
def handler():
    try:
        g_val = float(g.get())
        a_val = float(a.get())
        b_val = float(b.get())
        c_val = float(c.get())
        d_val = float(d.get())
        e_val = float(e.get())
        f_val = float(f.get())
        inserter(problem(a_val,b_val,c_val,d_val,e_val,f_val, g_val))
    except ValueError:
            inserter("Enter more values")

w=Text(Top, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bd=6)
w.grid(row=4, column=1)

info6=Button(Top, font=("arial", 10,"bold"), text="Optimize", bd=8,                                 command=handler)
info6.grid(row=4, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you're calling problem() you're sending it a_val, b_val_, c_val etc. You'll need to identify those in your function as arguments. try def problem(*arg)

Comment: @cjonesrun I don't think `*args` will help; the OP seems to want to use the parameter values in the function body, so they need to declare the parameters by name: `def problem(a, b, c, d, e, f, g):`.

Comment: You write `problem(a_val,b_val,c_val,d_val,e_val,f_val, g_val)`, but you defined the function without parameters.

Comment: _"At this point I am not sure I understand what this TypeError is trying to tell me."_ - it's trying to tell you that `problem` is designed to take zero arguments, but you're giving it 7. I'm not sure how much more clear the error could possibly be.

Comment: @abarnert -good point, I overlooked that. OP I would go with abarnert's suggestion to pass each individual value that you'll use in your function.

Comment: Try changing the first line of the function definition to `def problem(a, b, c, d, e, f, g):`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `problem()` method which takes 0 arguments, yet you try to call it passing some arguments. Either your method's definition should be changed to take those arguments and in this case it seems logical to change the method body to handle those parameters, or call `problem()` without passing parameters.